# How to summarize the multiplication of two columns per each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello this is my SQL query that multiplies values x and y according to conditions but only for one row.

`SELECT x * y FROM  bedrooms As TotalCapacity WHERE event=@event AND year=@year`

May I know how it should be improved to go row by row?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Lets say that for this query are 4 rows in result. Each row has X and Y value so I need to do X*Y for row 1 + X*Y for row 2 + X*Y for row 3..

Sorry for not being clear at the very first moment.

First bedroom X(2) Y(10) = 20

Second bedroom X(3) Y(5) = 15

Desired result = 35

Comment: to run `x * y` against all records remove the WHERE clause

Comment: Um, it already does that (unless your predicate is too narrow)

Comment: Please try to explain what you want with more details

Comment: @Linger can you please see my edit?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(x * y) ...`? Show example data and desired results.

Comment: @MartinSmith Edited the question with example

Comment: So that is what you need then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need

```
SELECT SUM(x * y) AS TotalCapacity
FROM   bedrooms
```

Comment: sorry this is off-topic but when I use ExecuteScalar in c# it does only the first line.

Comment: That's what `ExecuteScalar` does. [returns the first column of the first row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) Use `ExecuteReader` to loop through multiple rows. This query only returns one column and one row anyway though.

Comment: @Marek - No the query in my answer doesn't. It sums the individual capacities for all rows in the table and presents the total as a single value. [SQL Fiddle with the data in the question](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51a56/1)

Comment: my mistake, sorry, your query works very well. Thank you for your help.